# How to get the WFP routine address dynamically?

Tags: windows, driver, wfp

I am writing a Windows network filter driver for **WinXP(Using TDI tech)** and **win7(Using WFP tech)**, and I hope the driver is compatible with WinXP and Win7.

Because the **WFP** is only available from vista and later, so, I have to get the **WFP** routine(for example: **FwpmEngineOpen0**,**FwpsCalloutRegister0**) addresses dynamically, or the driver can NOT be load under WinXP.

But when I use **MmGetSystemRoutineAddress** to try to get **FwpmEngineOpen0** routine address,the routine always return 0 under Win7.

The MSDN said:"*MmGetSystemRoutineAddress ... Drivers can use this routine to determine if a routine is available on a specific version of Windows. It can only be used for routines exported by the kernel or HAL, not for any driver-defined routine.*"

So,is that **MmGetSystemRoutineAddress** can NOT fetch the **WFP** routine address?

How can I solve this if I want to get the **WFP** routine addresses dynamically?

Thanks for any help that can be given!

Comment: MmGetSystemRoutineAddress can only acquire functions of hal and ntosknl. Perhaps you are trying to cover all of xp to win10 with a single driver, but I hope you do not waste your time. It is recommended to build with Vista + dedicated driver just after Vista. After Win10, the EV signing issue is waiting for you, so your goal is hardly achieved anyway.